# Tabletop offcut for cutting board, finishing

Tags: sanding, finish-selection

I bought a Gerton top for a desk and it is great.  I bought a second one and made some shelves from that.  I am very happy with this product.

My question is, I have some material left and would like to make a cutting board out of it.  I want to be sure that this material (or the finish on it) is safe for that.

I can sand this if necessary.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SE. We have multiple previous Q&As that touch on cutting boards directly or indirectly. Here's one of the direct ones, [Food Safe Finish for Cutting Board](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/7067/food-safe-finish-for-cutting-board). Please note the first Comment from me, while many people have opinions to the contrary **all** finishes can actually be considered food-safe once they have fully cured. More on this in [this previous Answer](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/6054/what-finish-is-suitable-for-a-childrens-toy/6055#6055).

Comment: Now in relation to a Gerton offcut specifically, you can use it as a cutting board as-is (treating it with nothing further and just keep it clean with regular washing, as with any cutting surface or chopping board), apply a salad-bowl finish, oil it or wax it as you prefer. The choice is totally up to you, but the board will be perfectly hygienic and *will* endure if used bare. Many people use unfinished boards that are a decade or more old (mine is nearing 40). And of course the no-finish option means upkeep is simplest as you will never have to top up the coating or refinish it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Food Safe Finish for Cutting Board](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/7067/food-safe-finish-for-cutting-board)